# R.java is not generating neither with eclipse nor with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am having trouble with the development of my app, I can't go on because R.java is not generating.
I tried everything I could find of advice on Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that worked. The problem not only occurs in Eclipse but also in Android Studio. I checked all my xml files but couldn't find something that should stop the generating of R.java.
This is the content of my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewprogramming.android.timetoswim"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.thenewprogramming.android.timetoswim.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.thenewprogramming.android.timetoswim.AddMatchActivity"
            android:label="@string/AddMatchActivity_ActivityTitle"  
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" >

            <intent-filter >
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.thenewprogramming.android.timetoswim.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/SettingsActivity_ActivityTitle" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">

            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried wiping out all the other xml and that didn't work so I just placed them back.

All help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:
Someone else told me immediately that the strings have to begin with a lowercase letter so i did that and it worked! unfortunately he deleted the post but i will mark the question as answered (if i know how to do that...).

Comment: Desn't output console of eclipse have any errors?

Comment: Does Eclipse give any errors in any of your XML files?

Comment: @ReijerTheCoder can you write the edit as an answer, and mark it as accepted please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever your generated R class isn't generated, it indicates that there's a problem with generating it due to some parsing issue from the XML resources. Check the error console in your IDE to figure out what's specifically wrong.

Common problems are:

- An unescaped character in your `strings.xml`, for instance `you're` instead of `you\'re`
- Missing `layout_width` or `layout_height` tags in layout resources
- Missing namespace declarations
- Variable names that aren't supported by Java, for instance due to capitalization or use of spaces, hyphens or other unsupported characters
- Any other kind of syntax error in XML

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Eclipse, but the most recent version of Android Studio (0.1.6) has a known bug like this that only has a workaround at this point. The workaround is to turn off external build in preferences > compiler.

Comment: huge help...easy to waste an hour wondering why you updated Android Studio to 0.1.6 and your R.java doesn't compile even though nothing changed.